# Convert prop to propfull in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, code-snippets

Is there a shortcut or menu-option to convert a prop snippet?

```
 public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

to propfull snippet

```
private string _someProperty;
public string SomeProperty
{
get { return _someProperty;}
set { _someProperty = value;}
}
```

It would come in handy to add extra functionality.

Comment: That actually would be the only useful (for me) snippet. Typing is for some reasons faster for me, than replacing text in snippets. From other side, replacing `string` twice afterwards, having to add value to a field.. hmm, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Visual Studio that does this (as far as I know). Resharper has a "To property with backing field" refactoring though.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was 8 Years ago but i found an answer

Go to Tools > Options

[image: Set this to 'Never']

Then go to your property and press Ctrl + .

[image: And choose 'Convert to full property']